# What is correlationism?

Tags: objects

I've read definitions but it's not clear to me. Is it correlationist to say that every state of affairs we imagine must include someone imagining it? Would any philosophers argue *for* that, and if not then would they in some limited form -- for example yes but only when describing consciousness?

Comment: [Correlationism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/correlationism): "The philosophical standpoint, **rejected by proponents of speculative realism**, that we cannot directly access *thinking* and *being*, but only the correlation between them." See Immanuel Kant.

Comment: [Speculative realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_realism): "spec.realist thinkers have a resistance to philosophies of human finitude inspired by the tradition of Kant. What unites the members of the movement is an attempt to overcome both "correlationism" and "philosophies of access". Meillassoux defines correlationism as "the idea according to which we only ever have access to the correlation between thinking and being, and never to either term considered apart from the other." Phil.of access are any of those philosophies which privilege the human being over other entities."

Comment: thanks for the comments. is the question unclear @MauroALLEGRANZA